# Split a console into two different parts in C

Tags: c, console, ansi-c

How do I split a console into two parts? I'm trying to build a simple chat in C and I'd like to have the output on the top of the console and the input on one line at the bottom. I would assign the output handling to one thread and the input handling to another thread. For example:

```
Connected to server!
User1: Hello!
User2: How are you?


Write something here: simple TCP chat
```

---

```
User1: Hello!
User2: How are you?
You: simple TCP chat

Write something here:
```

Is it even possible to achieve something like this in plain C?
Thank you in advance!

PS: This question has already been asked some time ago, but the code is in C#, not C.

Comment: Read about [ncurses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) for a reasonably portable solution; othewise, with just plain standard library C, you need to use system specific tweaks.

Comment: It is only possible if the console supports control sequences like vt52 for example.

Comment: Thank you both! I think I'll use ncurses.